# Python version management and package installs

Tags: python, packages

After having issues tracking down an error on RPI3 - No Module Named ImageTk - I decided to do a complete reinstall of the operating system and start with a clean system.  After doing so, the same error occurred.  After reading several posts I make sure to install python-pil.imagetk, python-imaging-tk, python3-pil.imagetk, python3-pil-imagetk-dbg.  After doing so, I still have the same error.

Python --version returns 2.7.9 - yet with my IDE I can also run 3 and 3.4.2.  The error seems to occur in all cases.

In /usr/bin I have executables for python, python2, python2.7,python3,python3.4 - which I think is standard.

In /usr/lib I have an interesting mix of folders.  None of them contains ImageTk.  The python2.6 folder has only dist-packages and no mention of Image.  The python 2.7 folder has many files and folders, including a comprehensive dist-packages, but no Image.  Python3 folder has just dist-packages and no Image. The Python3.4 folder has many files and folders like 2.7.

My code is as follows - but it crashes on the Import ImageTk.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                   

from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image #, ImageTk
import ImageTk



    class Application(Frame):
        """ build a basic window frame """

        def __init__(self, master):
            super(Application, self).__init__(master)
            self.grid()
            self.create_widgets()

        def create_widgets(self):
            self.label1 = Label(self, text='My Label')
            self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

            self.button1 = Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.display)
            self.button1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky = W)

            # create larger button
            # use lambda: to prevent event function from executing when defined
            self.largeButton1 = Button(self, text="Push Me", command=lambda: 
            self.displayWithParameter("One"))
            self.largeButton1.config(width=4, height=3)
            self.largeButton1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky =W)

            self.largeButton2 = Button(self, text="Push Me", command=lambda: 
            self.displayWithParameter("Two"))
            self.largeButton2.config(width=4, height=3)
            self.largeButton2.grid(row=1, column=6, sticky =W)

            my_image = Image.open("Play30.png")

            filename= ImageTk.PhotoImage(my_image)

            # put image on label
            label = Label(image=filename)
            label.image = filename # keep a reference!
            label.grid()

            #put image on button
            self.imageButton1 = Button(self, text="", image=filename, 
            command=self.display)
            self.imageButton1.config(width=90, height=90)
            self.imageButton1.grid(row=4, column=10, sticky =W)
    def display(self):
        # event handler for button          
        print("The button was clicked")

    def displayWithParameter(self, varString):
        print(varString)



root = Tk()
root.title('Application Window')

w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
app = Application(root)
app.mainloop()
```

So when I install these various python imaging packages I am not sure where they are going - that is, to which version.

I have seen many posts for this ImageTk problem on the net, with many answers, but none of them seems to work.  Perhaps I am just looking in the wrong place.

Comment: I assume this worked since you accepted the answer, but it is exactly the same info I gave you in a comment to your previous question. You should also delete your other question as it is a duplicate and this one has an accepted answer.

Comment: Had to reinstall OS for this to work. System won't let me delete the previous post. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python 2.x try this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pil python-imaging python-imaging-tk
```

then open the Python console (type python on the command line) and type this:

```
import ImageTk
```

if it returns nothing everything is working.

If you intend to run this in Python2.x you probably need to change:

```
from tkinter import *
```

to

```
from Tkinter import *
```

The module name is capitalized differently for Python 2 and Python 3.